# Parsing list of lists for Transition state for DFA in python

Tags: dfa

class DFA:

```
#Q=list of strings, alphabet = list of single char strings, s = start
#state, F = list of states(strings) from Q, delta = list of lists
def __init__(self, Q, alphabet, s, F, delta):
    self.states = Q
    self.alphabet = alphabet
    self.startS = s
    self.finalS = F
    self.delta = delta
    self.currentState = self.startS
    return

def transition_to_nextState(self,input_value):           
    if ((self.currentState + input_value) not in self.delta):
        self.currentState = None
        return self.currentState
    self.currentState = self.delta[self.currentState]
    return self.currentState

#go to start state
def isStartState(self):
    self.currentState = self.startS
    #print(self.startS)

#check in final state
def isAcceptState(self):
    if (self.currentState in self.finalS):
        print("accepted")
        return True
    else:
        print("not accepted")
        return False

#return True if inputStr is accepted and False if not
def processInputStr(self,inputStr):
    self.isStartState()
    for letter in inputStr:
        print("input:",letter)
        self.currentState = self.transition_to_nextState(letter)
        print("current state:", self.currentState)
        if (self.currentState == None):
            return self.isAcceptState()
        continue
    return self.isAcceptState()
```

My transition_to_nextState function is not working.

The DFA is being sent:
Q: ['q1','q2','q3']
alphabet: ['0','1']
s: 'q1'
F: ['q2']
delta: [['q1','a','q1'],['q1','b','q2]]

I can't parse the list to find the next state that the machine should transition to. Any ideas would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in this line

```
if ((self.currentState + input_value) not in self.delta)
```

the expression self.currentState + input_value will gives you a concatenated string i.e. if input_value = '1' then this will gives you q11

while the self.delta is a list of lists, you can't match a string with a list.

Comment: How would I go about matching a string with a list? Should i convert the list to a string?

Comment: While converting the list to string based will help for matching. But I suspect there is something not quite right with the self.delta itself.

Answer (score 0):

I guessed you are using the delta list as the states transition. So if given that self.currentState="q1" and input_value="a", I suppose you want to find in the list the next state that would be "q1" based on your input. Perhaps changing the delta to a dictionary of tuple = state will help

```
# input to self.delta
delta = {('q1','a'):'q1', ('q1','b'): 'q2'}

# modify this line 
def transition_to_nextState(self,input_value):           
    if ((self.currentState, input_value) not in self.delta):
        self.currentState = None
        return self.currentState
    self.currentState = self.delta[(self.currentState,input_value)]
    return self.currentState
```